# Partitioning square root of natural numbers into two sets for closest sum?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, discrete-mathematics

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. It asks to divide square root of the numbers from 1 to n into two sets A and B such that the sum of numbers in Set A is as close as possible to the sum of the numbers in set B.
I have tried quite hard to,but I am unable to come up with an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

- Imagine `n` numbers (real numbers) in non-decreasing order, which is
  your case. `sqr(n)` will always be greater than `sqr(n - 1)`.
- Reverse the list.
- Create 4 variables, `setA`, `setB` as empty arrays, and `sumA`, `sumB` as numbers initialized to 0.
- Pick first value from reversed list and append it to `setA` and add to `sumA`.
- Iterate over rest of the reversed list and append & add to set & sum respectively whose sum is less than <s>current value</s> the other.

From top of my head:

```
f(divide_in_2_groups) <- (list)
  setA, setB = []
  sumA, sumB = 0

  append setA, list[0]
  sumA <- sumA + list[0]

  for i <- 1 to n
    //if sumA >= list[i]
    if sumA >= sumB
      append setB, list[i]
      sumB <- sumB + list[i]
    else
      append setA, list[i]
      sumA <- sumA + list[i]

  return (setA, sumA, setB, sumB, abs(sumA - sumB))
```

HTH

Comment: I believe this algorithm will not yield the right result. Can you post a proof that this will work ?

Comment: Sorry, since I wrote it from top of my head, I made a mistake in algorithm. Please see my updated answer.